# Selecting Variable to Plot in Shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I am creating an app in Shiny where I want to change my y-variable of a scatter plot in ggplot based on user input. However I am having trouble determining how to change the plot based on the user input. I have the following code:

ui

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
tags$head(
tags$style(HTML("
 .multicol {
   -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
   column-count: 3;
    }
   "))
  ),

  titlePanel(h1('NBA MVPs', align = "center")),
  hr(),
  mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(type='tabs',
            tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
            tabPanel("Description",
                     p("Blah, blah")))),
  hr(),
  fluidRow(
  column(2,
       selectInput('stat', "Statistics", choices=c('Field Goal %'=FG.Perc, '3 Pt. %'=ThreePointPerc,"Free Throw %" = "FTPerc", "Rebounds" = "TRB", "Assists" ="ASST", 'Steals' = "STL", "Points" = "PTS", "True Shooting %"= "TrueShootingPerc", "Eff. FG %"= "eFG", "Total Reb. %" = "TRBPerc", "Off. Rating" = "ORtg", "Def. Rating" = "DRtg")))
),
 wellPanel(
tags$div(class = "multicol", checkboxGroupInput("player", choices = c('one' = '1', 'two' = '2'), label = "Player/Year", selected = c('1', '2')
      ))
 )
```

server

```
library(shiny); library(dplyr); library(mosaic); library(ggplot2)
MVP = MVPData
shinyServer(function(input, output){
 plotData <- reactive({ 
var = input$stat
df <- MVPData %>%
  filter(player %in% input$player)
 df}
 )
  output$plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(plotData(), aes(x=Rk, y=input$stat, color=player)) + geom_point())
})
```

Right now, the scatter plot reads the user input as the same string for every player, so there is just a straight line of data. If I remove the quotations from the choices, I get an error saying that the object is not found. I also tried calling the choices using the names() function, since the choices are columns of the data set, but then I got an error about an unexpected end of input.

The outupt of dput(head(MVPData))) is:

```
structure(list(V1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), Rk = 1:6, 
G = 1:6, Date = c("2004-11-03", "2004-11-05", "2004-11-06", 
"2004-11-09", "2004-11-10", "2004-11-13"), Age = c("30-270", 
"30-272", "30-273", "30-276", "30-277", "30-280"), Team = c("PHO", 
"PHO", "PHO", "PHO", "PHO", "PHO"), H.A = c("", "@", "@", 
"@", "@", ""), Opponent = c("ATL", "PHI", "NJN", "CHI", "CLE", 
"SAC"), Outcome = c("W (+30)", "W (+10)", "W (+32)", "W (+20)", 
"L (-5)", "L (-2)"), GS = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), 
MP = c("24:00:00", "32:00:00", "37:00:00", "33:00:00", "50:00:00", 
"36:00:00"), FG = c(6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 11L), FGA = c(12L, 
5L, 8L, 9L, 13L, 16L), FG.Perc = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.75, 0.333, 
0.385, 0.688), ThreePtFG = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 5L), ThreePtFGA = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 8L), ThreePointPerc = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0.333, 
0.625), FT = c(0L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L), FTA = c(0L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 6L, 2L), FTPerc = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 0.667, 1), ORB = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L), DRB = c(3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L), TRB = c(3L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 3L), ASST = c(4L, 10L, 8L, 12L, 17L, 7L), 
STL = c(2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BLK = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), TOV = c(3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L), PF = c(2L, 5L, 
0L, 3L, 5L, 3L), PTS = c(12L, 9L, 17L, 8L, 15L, 29L), GmSc = c(7.9, 
8.9, 17.4, 10, 18.5, 24.6), Plus.Minus = c(17L, 4L, 21L, 
21L, 1L, 4L), Regular = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), TrueShootingPerc = c(0.5, 
0.765, 0.871, 0.405, 0.48, 0.859), eFG = c(0.5, 0.7, 0.813, 
0.333, 0.423, 0.844), ORBPerc = c(0, 0, 4.2, 0, 1.9, 7.4), 
DRBPerc = c(9.2, 14.3, 2.9, 6.9, 13, 3.3), TRBPerc = c(5.5, 
6.7, 3.4, 4.1, 7.1, 5.3), ASTPerc = c(24.2, 43.5, 33.2, 63.2, 
50.5, 35.4), STLPerc = c(3.9, 0, 4.5, 0, 0, 0), BLKPerc = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TOVPerc = c(20, 40.5, 38.1, 9.2, 6, 15.1), 
USGPerc = c(24.8, 12.8, 20.7, 14.9, 13.8, 24.6), ORtg = c(98L, 
118L, 122L, 115L, 124L, 163L), DRtg = c(80L, 106L, 96L, 88L, 
109L, 135L), Plus.Minus2 = c(7.9, 8.9, 17.4, 10, 18.5, 24.6
), postMVP = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), player = c("2", 
"2", "1", "2", "1", "2"
)), .Names = c("V1", "Rk", "G", "Date", "Age", "Team", "H.A", 
"Opponent", "Outcome", "GS", "MP", "FG", "FGA", "FG.Perc", "ThreePtFG", 
"ThreePtFGA", "ThreePointPerc", "FT", "FTA", "FTPerc", "ORB", 
"DRB", "TRB", "ASST", "STL", "BLK", "TOV", "PF", "PTS", "GmSc", 
"Plus.Minus", "Regular", "TrueShootingPerc", "eFG", "ORBPerc", 
"DRBPerc", "TRBPerc", "ASTPerc", "STLPerc", "BLKPerc", "TOVPerc", 
"USGPerc", "ORtg", "DRtg", "Plus.Minus2", "postMVP", "player"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: (nil)>, row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: can you include the output of `dput(head(MVPData))` in your question ?

Comment: @SymbolixAU, I've updated the post with the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my understanding that `ggplot2` "prefers" melted data, so I would do something like:

```
MVPData_melted <- melt(MVPData, id.vars = c("V1", "Rk","G","Date","Age","Team","H.A","Opponent","Outcome", "player"))
## double check this melt does what you need
```

And then filter on the 'variable' column

```
library(shiny); library(dplyr); library(mosaic); library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
                        .multicol {
                        -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
                        -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
                        column-count: 3;
                        }
                        "))
        ),

    titlePanel(h1('NBA MVPs', align = "center")),
    hr(),
    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type='tabs',
                        tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
                        tabPanel("Description",
                                p("Blah, blah")))),
    hr(),
    fluidRow(
        column(2,
            selectInput('stat', "Statistics", choices=c('Field Goal %'="FG.Perc", '3 Pt. %'="ThreePointPerc","Free Throw %" = "FTPerc", "Rebounds" = "TRB", "Assists" ="ASST", 'Steals' = "STL", "Points" = "PTS", "True Shooting %"= "TrueShootingPerc", "Eff. FG %"= "eFG", "Total Reb. %" = "TRBPerc", "Off. Rating" = "ORtg", "Def. Rating" = "DRtg")))
    ),
    wellPanel(
        tags$div(class = "multicol", checkboxGroupInput("player", choices = c('one' = '1', 'two' = '2'), label = "Player/Year", selected = c('1', '2')
        ))
    )
)


server <- function(input, output){

    plotData <- reactive({ 
        var = input$stat
        ## now filtering on var using the melted data
        df <- MVPData_melted %>%
            filter(player %in% input$player,
                         variable == var)
        df
        })

## i've moved the plot into its own function
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(plotData(), aes(x=Rk, y=value, color=player)) + 
        geom_point()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don you try something like this

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    selectedaxis <- input$selectaxis


    ifelse(test = selectedaxis == "input$selectedaxis",
           yes = ggplot(plotData(), aes(x=Rk, y=input$stat, color=player)) + geom_point(),
           no = ggplot(plotData(), aes(x=Rk, y=input$stat, color=player)) + geom_point()
           )
    })
```

Comment: I don't understand what is inside the conditional statement please, could you please elaborate, specifically what is test and what the conditional is checking for?